# Is it possible to copy all the possible results from a query via _GET of a website that I don't have FTP or database access?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the data from a third party website that has some public data, more specifically, Catholic Daily Liturgy from http://www.cnbb.org.br.

They have it in Portuguese until the end of the year 2013. All you need to do to change the content is change the variables values on the url. (`$ano`, `$mes`, `$dia`) <- Portugues for Year, Month and Day.

http://www.cnbb.org.br/liturgia/app/user/user/UserView.php?ano=2013&mes=7&dia=1

I've trying to download this data, but so far no success. Do you guys have any ideas about how should I approach this thing?

Comment: what have you tried?  `file_get_contents('http://www.cnbb.org.br/liturgia/app/user/user/UserView.php?ano=2013&mes=7&dia=1');` ???

Comment: I was trying to do it with excel web querie, but this php function seems to be doing the job. Thank you :)

Comment: What does "no success" mean? You need to be more specific when asking questions like this.

Comment: yes sir... and no success meant complete fail by the time. I got it going now though. I'm using REGEX to break down the data that Im getting with the file_get_contents function.

Answer (score 6):

Use `file_get_contents`

```
file_get_contents(
    'http://www.cnbb.org.br/liturgia/app/user/user/UserView.php?a‌​no=2013&mes=7&dia=1'
);
```

See the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)